# how to set height of a 'td' inside a array in javascript using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

```
cell=new Array();
//some code lines

// here 'k' is number of a FOR LOOP and this part work well
cell[k]=document.createElement('td'); 

cell[k].style.height="50px"; // problem occur in here
```

my question is how can i set 50px height to newly created 'td'.

*my full code below

```
var myColumns= result.array2[0];
var myRows= result.array2[1];
var cellData="";
var mmm=0;
var kkk=2;

    row=new Array();
    cell=new Array();

    row_num=parseInt(myRows+1);          
    cell_num=parseInt(myColumns); 

    tab=document.createElement('table');

    tab.id="newtable";       
    tab.border="5";     
    tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
```

create rows

```
    for(c=0;c<row_num;c++){
    row[c]=document.createElement('tr');
```

create cells

```
    for(k=0;k<cell_num;k++) {           
    cell[k]=document.createElement('td');
```

below first line not work, without that line code work well

```
    cell[k].style.height="50px";        
    if(c==0){           
            cont=document.createTextNode( result.array2[kkk])
            kkk++;

        }else{              
            cont=document.createTextNode( result.array1[mmm])
            mmm++;
            }   

    cell[k].appendChild(cont);
    row[c].appendChild(cell[k]);
    }
    tbo.appendChild(row[c]);
    }
    tab.appendChild(tbo);
```

'otherTopSection' is a div id name

```
document.getElementById('otherTopSection').appendChild(tab);
```

Comment: What is that _problem_? It should work. Do you append the element?

Comment: That would work; but the `<td>` elements of a row will all be the same height; so if there's a sibling `<td>` with a bigger height then each cell in the row will be *that*, greater, height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell[k]=document.createElement('td');
cell[k].style.height="50px";     
someTr.appendChild(cell[k]);
```

Looks like it's not appended to the DOM.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thelgevold/gpkjj7er/3/

Comment: var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.style.height="50px";  this code work, but try to replace it with cell[k] array!!!

Comment: thank you, now i understood the situation , above your code work